# Move script from body to head

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm running into an issue with WordPress and form embeds. I have a page built via WP Bakery and one of the block allows a user to embed a form onto the page.

This however is causing the form to load in slow (sometimes takes up to three seconds for the form to load in).

As a solution to this, I'm trying to get the `<script>` tags to render in the `head` rather than in the `body`.

Is this even possible? The `script` needs to move into the `head` before page load so that the form renders in - but unsure if this is even feasible?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach `async` in  to load script asynchrony.

```
<script async src="..."></script>
```